# How to set a text note of calendar for to do click and run my app?

Tags: blackberry, calendar, onclicklistener

I want that, when I click a text from ANY app installed in my device, run my app. It´s like when you click and url, and run browser automatically.
More specifically, I need to do click in a specific text note of my calendar and run my app.
Can this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It´s done!

A perfect example in https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ui_active_text_fields_1988859_11.html